# How to increase the download speed of Torrent on Android Mobile?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, downloading

I own Xperia Mini Pro. Recently I came to know that there are some Torrents Clients available on Android Market. So I installed [aDownloader](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.DroiDownloader) to download some movies from Torrent server. I want to know if there are any tricks to speed up the Download on Android mobile. And I am using 2.75G(Edge) data connection to download. I found the average download speed on this connection is 25kB/sec.

Pl let me know the same on WiFi connection. The average download speed using WiFi connection is around 50kB/sec.

Comment: Might not be what you want, but you could use remote torrent to control the downloads onto your home PC, Windows Home Server, etc. Then you can stream (using Windows Media Centre, Windows Home Server, etc.)

Comment: If you download a file with more seeds and peers, your speed will increase. It could just be that your particular torrent has very few seeders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Edge connection by itself is so slow compared to the normal torrent download speeds that it makes no sense to optimize the downloads. The ping times on the connection are so high that constant peer switching will slow the download if you attempt to download from several peers simultaneously. Your best bet would be to try to find a couple of good peers to fill your bandwidth and stick with them, or stop+restart the torrent to get new peers.

Answer (score 1):

As onik notes, your connection is simply too slow.  But I also had terrible speeds when I tried aDownloader on an HSPA+ network.  I believe this is due to traffic shaping.  [tTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tagsoft.ttorrent.pro) supports encryption and the Pro version has no download limit, so that might help; it's worked very well for me.

Comment: Keep in mind that traffic shaping is not done on all networks, so it depends on your carrier. Over here I got 2mbps speeds over HSDPA with default settings on a Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah we can control Torrent speed.

Go to settings then maximize download speed and minimize upload speed of your torrent client. By this a difference will be created.